# Circuit Analysis for Frequency-to-Voltage converter

Tags: converter, frequency-measurement

I'm struggling to understand how this FV converter by bob pease works.

[image]

It's published here https://www.electronicdesign.com/technologies/digital-ics/article/21800808/whats-all-this-frequencytovoltage-converter-stuff-anyhow

I have no problem with the input section and with the optional output sallen-key filter.

What I'm having difficult to follow is the FV converter itself (after the 3300pf cap).
I kind of see this is an integrator which makes plenty of sense of course, but I'm intrigued mostly by the input transistor section and the diode to compensate frequency on inverted input of A2.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: If you simulated it you might get good insight.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes I did enter it on LTSpice and works wonderful. I could tweak it to 100KHz also.
But I'm more trying to understand the design rationale.

Comment: I'm no whizbang. But the BJT whose emitter is at the 3300 pF cap is in cascode mode. The two diodes at the base and the 150k resistor there make for a 90 uA current into the diode pair which probably means about -1.3 V at the BJT base. As the 24 k feedback resistor won't deliver more than 410 uA back to the (-) input, the BJT won't require enough base current to matter against that 90 uA flow. The collector is held up high enough that the BJT will be in active mode. Current pulled out of the cascode BJT will be forced through RF to generate the output. We on the same page?

Comment: The [sub-circuit on left is the same as the sub-circuit on right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZeoA.png), correct? Agreed? This establishes a voltage at the silicon BJT base shown in the diagram. (\$\beta\$ at room temp of about 100 to 150, but as low as 20/30 at very low temps.) So the BJT has its base nailed down. Because of the diode pair, whose voltage differences vary as the log of the current, variations in BJT base current can at most mean a difference (even at very cold vs very hot temperatures) of \$\le 10\:\text{mV}\$ at the base. So the BJT's base voltage is rock-stable.

Comment: Thank you @periblepsis for your insigts. Yes it's the same circuit. So this way of biasing the transistor base would be meant to be temperature stable. 
So the rationale of this common-base transistor is to isolate the currents flowing on each side?